# How to get unique values from a specific column from multiple sheets in a separate sheet using Excel or Google sheets?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

**Project1**(Sheet1)

[Packages] [VersionNumber] [License]

ABC         1.0.1           MIT

*Project2*(Sheet2)

[Packages] [VersionNumber] [License]

ABC          1.0.1          MIT

XYZ          2.0.1          Apache

**Expected Output:**
*SummarySheet*

[Packages] [VersionNumber] [License]

ABC           1.0.1          MIT

XYZ           2.0.1          Apache

How can I write a query to get unique values based on the Packages Columns in the Summary Sheet?
thanks in advance!!

Comment: GS is different to Excel. Please pick the one you plan to use and don't forget to include what you researched and tried. SO is no free coding website.

Comment: What if there're multiple `VersionNumber` for the same `Package`? Should each `VersionNumber` show up in the output?

Comment: In that case, I want the package with the highest version number. @lamblichus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=QUERY(UNIQUE({Sheet2!A2:C;Sheet3!A2:C}),"select * where Col1 is not null")
```

Comment: This is not working for me.

Comment: what is your locale? can you share a spreadsheet? as far it's working well for me.

Comment: Here is the google sheets link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19I7blawu2komQ6qXFSo58NWKLNkyYfTX3fUKxDQW0RQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Done, let me know if it is ok!

Comment: That was working. How can we handle if there are duplicate version numbers for different packages? Right now it is giving reference error: Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in B6.

Comment: For such a function, you need sufficient space below for all the unique values.

Comment: Sufficient Space meaning?

Comment: that means that you have to leave blank cells all around to allow the formula to expand

Answer (score 0):

For `Excel Office 365`, assuming *Sheet1* and *Sheet2* are **consecutive** worksheets within the workbook and that `A2:C3` contains the relevant data in both:

`=LET(ζ,Sheet1:Sheet2!A2:C3,UNIQUE(INDEX(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",,ζ)&"</b></a>","//b"),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(ζ)/3,3))))`

Note that it would not be a good idea here to 'cover your bases' by replacing the range `A2:C3` with, for example, a range comprising entire columns (`A:C`).